# Driving events across custom TCP Long-Polling server

Tags: c#, events, mobile, tcp, long-polling

I’m trying to write a custom TCP based long polling server that will serve as a go-between for other TCP connections that require more persistence than a mobile phone can provide.

The way I’m trying to do it is writing an asynchronous TCP server in C# and a matching TCP Client also written in C#.

The way that long polling works (as far as I understand it) is that you open a TCP connection to a server, and the server Halts before sending data back across the socket.  You find a Heartbeat interval that works on a mobile phone network (I’ve heard that around 8 minutes works?) and you send an empty packet if there is no updated data.

This is where my trouble comes in.  I can’t figure out how to “link” my client’s request for data with an event handler running on the server…

The flow should be something like this (“client” is on a phone):

1. User starts my application
2. Client sends a request to be notified if data has changed
3. Server “links” (registers) client’s socket object into an “Event handler” that is called by the server’s other TCP connections that I talked about!
4. Event

   o   If it is triggered (new data has arrived), Send the data to the client

   o   If it isn’t triggered (no new data), Send an “EmptyChanges” packet to client
5. Client receives data on the phone and processes it (calls an event handler based on what type of packet it received and passes the “data” it got from the server to it)
6. Client sends a request to be notified if data has changed

So, my problem is that I can’t think of a design that will accomplish what I want it to do.  The problem is that I don’t know HOW to do #3.  How do I “Link” one event handler from another?  And these are almost guaranteed to be running on different threads!

So, my application would look something like this (all psuedocode):

```
Class AppClass
{
    Main()

    List<Client> clients;
    List<DataServers> dataServers;

    DataReceivedFromServer(Data stuff)
    {
    }

    MessageReceivedFromPhone(PhoneMessage pm, object sender)
    {
        //Loop here until HeartBeat interval reached
        Int totalTime = 0;
        While(totalTime < HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL)
        {
            If( ) // If we have received data from the server, and the client WANTED that data, send it now
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Kind of?  I want it to be event driven, but I'm having the damndest time figuring out how to drive the application with a PUSH driven style vs. what I'm "used" to of Polling.

Please, be kind as I might be doing something overly complicated and stupid because this is my first real attempt at using Socket programming (never needed it) and it's especially hard due to the nature of Cell phones being on transient networks and my server needing to maintain the location of these phones with an OPEN TCP connection.

> Server platform: Windows
>
> Server language: C#
>
> Test Client platform: Windows
>
> Test Client language: C#
>
> Target Client platform: Windows Mobile 6.5, iPhone, Android (clients will be written separately)
>
> Target client language: C#, Obj-C or MonoTouch, Java

Comment: Do all the clients need to receive the same data or is the data different for every client ? If the data is the same, a simple broadcast could be the easiest way: You simply "mark" your client as " listener " (simple boolean isListener or something) and then when data comes, you simple loop through the list of clients sending them the data

Comment: By The Way: This sounds a lot like a Message Queue. We have a similar thing running here for a completely different purpose but the idea is the same. You could use ActiveMQ message broker and simply set your phone to listen to a certain topic. On event you send the message (data) on that topic. As a bonus, the connection with ActiveMQ is pretty stable (using their client) and you don't have to dive into the illuster world of keeping tcp connections on bad network / cellphone connections which can be a real PITA

Comment: @Noctris:  That ActiveMQ looks very VERY interesting.  Pending more research, I think you may have found exactly what I was looking for, I was just not sure how to put what I needed into standard terms and such.

I'll read up more about specific ActiveMQ Transport (I think they used the term Publisher) layer implementation, and if I can customize it how I need it then it would be perfect!

Comment: @Noctris: Also, I didn't know that you were the first responder as well.  Yes, all the data's gonna be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just anyone wondering this, I trashed the idea of writing a custom TCP server to manage my connections.  There was so much overhead in doing that, I'd basically be replicating writing my own HTTP server, so instead of doing that, I went with the Web Tornado framework in Python as my server and am writing the back end services to communicate through HTTP requests in Web Tornado.

Instead of using Long polling at all, I'm going to use SMS for push notifications.  I believe all of the major phone platforms implement something similar to an SMS Interceptor that you write... if an SMS of a certain format comes through, it will run your custom code.  This allows me to remove the requirements of using consistent open connections (other than for live chat, which will use a comet style Long poll, but the connection can only remain open if active for about 5 minutes.)

Basically, the Web Tornado framework is serving as an Enterprise bus in my architecture.